# Handlebars missing style when sending email

Tags: css, node.js, express, nodemailer, express-handlebars

I have a node server that is sending emails templates.
When I'm opening that template **locally** it runs the CSS styles as properly at is should.
When I'm **sending** this as an a email to myself for testing some CSS doesn't apply.

**CSS being received from a test email:**

```css
mainCon {
  width: 936px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}
```

**Original full CSS:**

```css
mainCon {
  width: 936px;
  height: max-content;
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}
```

**Server (nodemailer):**

```
const mailOptions = {
  from: "email@yahoo.com",
  to: "email@yahoo.com",
  subject: `sub`,
  template:'index',
  context: {
    fullName: req.body.fullName,
    reason: req.body.reason,
    problem: req.body.problem,
  }
}
```

The CSS is inside the handlebars **style** component attached to the **head**

**handlebars html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainCon">
        <p class="title">title</p>
        <div class="nameNreasonCon">
            <div class="reasonCon">
                <p>{{reason}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nameCon">
                <p>{{fullName}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="problemCon">
            <p>{{problem}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the generated template output

Comment: @marc [link](https://ibb.co/s1gQjZf) this is how its look.  you meant this?

Comment: When you create an email template not all css rules are supported. Flexbox usually is not supported by the email clients. You can see the allowed rules for gmail (web) and others emails clients here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/email-client/gmail/